# User uploading 2nd image before deleting 1st image

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background** :

User click on **Mask** & upload their own image on the mask.

Once image uploaded, **Remove** Text is displaying on the image.

Once user click on Remove Text, we are **deleting** the uploaded image.

Also User can drag uploaded image....

[image]

**Issue** :

User can able to upload **another [2nd] image** before click on "Remove" button.

**Requirement** :

User should be able to upload another image **only after** click on "Remove" button....

**My work to get the solution** :

I added below 3 lines of code , after that i got solution in [Codepen1](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/EzQNJQ) , but now i can't able to drag the uploaded image....

```
$("#"+String(target)).css("pointer-events", "none");
$('.container').css('pointer-events','');
$(canvasId).css("pointer-events","");
```

**Code Snippet** :

```js
 var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 160,
            "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
            "y": 291,
            "height": 296,
            "width": 429,
            "name": "mask_1"
        }, {
            "x": 25,
            "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
            "height": 324,
            "width": 471,
            "y": 22,
            "name": "mask_2"
        }],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'http://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            // here
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {
   // my work
          //  $("#"+String(target)).css("pointer-events", "none");
   // end
                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                //  Remove image

                $("<br/><span id=\"" + newImageLoadedId + "\" class=\"remove\">Remove</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
                    "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
                    "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2 + 25) + "px"
                });

                $(".remove").click(function(event) {
    // my work
   // $('.container').css('pointer-events','');
    // end    
                    const canvasId = "canvas#" + event.currentTarget.id;
                    // Delete the uploaded image & icon
                    const ctx = $("canvas")[event.currentTarget.id].getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500)

                    // Delete the Remove button
                    $(this).remove();
     // my work
    // $(canvasId).css("pointer-events","");
     //end
     
                });

                // Remove image code end here....
            };
            counter++;
        }
        return mask;
    }
    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl)
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas
            container.drawMask()
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.drawMask = function() {
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
            context.restore();
            initImage = false;
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
           // console.log('Draw started');
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
           // console.log('Drag over');

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
      
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            container.drawMask();
                            container.drawImage();
                        }, 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            settings.scale = 1;
            settings.rotate = 0;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED
            // sirpepole Add this
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.remove {
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.remove:hover {
 background: white;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">

    <div id="container" class="container">
    </div>
```

Here is [Codepen2](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/arqpbK) ,  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/sm5q3wok/1/) , [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hDsMcP3c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a jQuery data object can help determine if an image has been set for a canvas or not.

I have added `image_set${id}` value and set it to true when a User uploads an image and set it to false after it has been removed.

Hope this helps :)

Check code below:

```js
 var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 160,
            "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
            "y": 291,
            "height": 296,
            "width": 429,
            "name": "mask_1"
        }, {
            "x": 25,
            "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
            "height": 324,
            "width": 471,
            "y": 22,
            "name": "mask_2"
        }],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
              if(!$(e.currentTarget).data('image_set'+target))
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'http://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            // here
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {
   // my work
          //  $("#"+String(target)).css("pointer-events", "none");
   // end
                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                //  Remove image

                $("<br/><span id=\"" + newImageLoadedId + "\" class=\"remove\">Remove</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
                    "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
                    "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2 + 25) + "px"
                });

                $(".remove").click(function(event) {
    // my work
   // $('.container').css('pointer-events','');
    // end    
                    const canvasId = "canvas#" + event.currentTarget.id;
                    // Delete the uploaded image & icon
                    const ctx = $("canvas")[event.currentTarget.id].getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
                    $('#container').data('image_set'+event.currentTarget.id, false)
                    // Delete the Remove button
                    $(this).remove();
     // my work
    // $(canvasId).css("pointer-events","");
     //end
     
                });

                // Remove image code end here....
            };
            counter++;
        }
        return mask;
    }
    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl, true)
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas
            container.drawMask()
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.drawMask = function() {
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
            context.restore();
            initImage = false;
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
           // console.log('Draw started');
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
           // console.log('Drag over');

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
      
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            container.drawMask();
                            container.drawImage();
                        }, 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl, isMask) {
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            settings.scale = 1;
            settings.rotate = 0;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED
            if(!isMask)
               container.data('image_set'+settings.id, true)
            // sirpepole Add this
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.remove {
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.remove:hover {
 background: white;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">

    <div id="container" class="container">
    </div>
```

**PS:** I would suggest using a framework given the complexity of your code even though the above code changes would help you.

Answer (score 0):

First let me purpose that coplex SPAs (Single page applications) should use some framework for binding JS variables, scope and DOM/shadow/canvas together.

Now for your problem.

It seems that this line is incorrect:

```
if (pixel[3] === 255) {
```

I guess you try to see if this is a white pixel.
But when you do `getImageData` the return value is in RGBA. Look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data).

So `pixel[3]` will get you the `opacity` value of the pixel (which is always 255).

Better changed to:

```
if (pixel.filter(function(n){ return n === 255}).length == 4) {
```

which guarantees you that this pixel is white.

Comment: thanks for the sugestion, i replaced the code that you posted in answer, but still it did't worked for me.... , here is code : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/d9nxuj3g/

Comment: It is working for me. Can you describe you problem exactly?

Comment: In the fiddle, can you please upload one image, then again upload one more image - its allowing to upload.... `but it should't, until we click on remove`......

Comment: Please use `console.log(pixel);` before this `if`, and read the log in the developer tools in your browser. it will show you the 4 elements in the array. if they all `255` that's a white pixel, so we let the user to upload the image.

Comment: i got this result :  https://prnt.sc/nsc5fh , please tell me what the next step....

Comment: You must click on non-white area. If you click on white pixel, the upload image will pop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193830/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-jonniejs).